# Does %EXP and % Magic Find from my follower count towards my character?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I equip a % EXP bonus or % Magic Find item to my follower, does it count towards my character?

Would inserting a [Gem of Ease](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem-of-ease) in my follower's jewelry count towards my exp?

Comment: At least partially answered, anyways.  I'm not 100% on the EXP %.  Incidentally, followers can't equip legendary gems, I don't think.

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to search for a question of the same wording on here and couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: No worries; that's what duplicates are all about.